# Decrypt SOAP Message

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I'm trying to decrypt a soap message but I'm getting the following error:

> Unable to retrieve the decryption key

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
doc.Load(stream);
var en = new EncryptedXml(doc);
en.AddKeyNameMapping(KeyName, Alg);
en.DecryptDocument();
```

I have added the certificate to my local box.  Do I need to specify them somewhere?  I have added the xml document.  So what would be the keyname and alg be? Is the keyname what is in the keystore?  The algorithm is what is in the xml document (sha1 which you can see in the document under DigestMethod Algorithm tag) ?

```
 <s:Envelope 
        xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
        xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <s:Header>
            <VsDebuggerCausalityData 
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">uIDPo4tYpt6X40FEk+VSAe5mc8MAAAAAP497cBuXfk+uFIOY80O0iuLtIW56q7hLktgVYPhbnHMACQAA
            </VsDebuggerCausalityData>
            <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" 
                xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                <o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-10490fb0-8ee0-4a4c-a8db-77242c9a3b7f-2" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">MIIF+TCCBOGgAwIBAgIQIWv3OdE866kXP/....t</o:BinarySecurityToken>
                <e:EncryptedKey Id="_0" 
                    xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                    <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p">
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" 
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" />
                    </e:EncryptionMethod>
                    <KeyInfo 
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                        <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                            <o:KeyIdentifier ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509SubjectKeyIdentifier" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">j0ZKFBmTz3Kj0cQ82rq63MYAR+0=</o:KeyIdentifier>
                        </o:SecurityTokenReference>
                    </KeyInfo>
                    <e:CipherData>
                        <e:CipherValue>ANCElFZ5v....==</e:CipherValue>
                    </e:CipherData>
                    <e:ReferenceList>
                        <e:DataReference URI="#_2" />
                    </e:ReferenceList>
                </e:EncryptedKey>
                <Signature 
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                    <SignedInfo>
                        <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                        <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
                        <Reference URI="#_1">
                            <Transforms>
                                <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                            </Transforms>
                            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                            <DigestValue>akiomlPdi6j1h6r9NDqmh9G1GD0=</DigestValue>
                        </Reference>
                    </SignedInfo>
                    <SignatureValue>LIjqWD/BXsoA0XNR7hv...==</SignatureValue>
                    <KeyInfo>
                        <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                            <o:Reference ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" URI="#uuid-10490fb0-8ee0-4a4c-a8db-77242c9a3b7f-2" />
                        </o:SecurityTokenReference>
                    </KeyInfo>
                </Signature>
            </o:Security>
        </s:Header>
        <s:Body u:Id="_1">
            <e:EncryptedData Id="_2" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content" 
                xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc" />
                <e:CipherData>
                    <e:CipherValue>3kESnJnhc8K.....</e:CipherValue>
                </e:CipherData>
            </e:EncryptedData>
        </s:Body>
    </s:Envelope>
```

Comment: The [example in the documentation shows that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.encryptedxml.decryptdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) a call to [AddKeyNameMapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.encryptedxml.addkeynamemapping(v=vs.110).aspx) is required, otherwise how would it know what decryption algorithm to use?

Comment: You need to provide much more details. Also pick some appropriate tags.

Comment: I added the xml document.  Sorry.

Comment: @RB  I'm a bit lost on how to use the AddKeyNameMapping in terms of a certificate.  Most examples state it will get it from the local certificates.  I have the certificates install on my machine but its not working still. Any ideas?  This example also says it should be reading it from the local store https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45059848/how-to-encrypt-decrypt-xml-wiith-x-509-certificate-correctly.